# ERROR Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager. IOS React Native

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, redux

I am trying to use `QRCode`in my application, but I am facing some errors
I installed

`yarn add react-native-svg react-native-qrcode-svg`

then
`react-native link react-native-svg`

then `cd ios && pod install`

and I am facing this error

[image]

I also cleaned the cache & deleted watchman, but that's didn't workout for me

any clues what is the problem or maybe solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't rebuilt your native code after installing react-native-svg, try running
react-native run-ios
or react-native run-android